# Verify if string contains at least one letter

Tags: c++

Hello Im trying to check if string contains at least one letter, but  at this stage is not working. If I type 13 it would continue without giving me error, 
It doesn't matter if contains number I just want at least one letter for example: Patrick1 thats okay.

This the code I'm trying :

```
 void setName(string b) {
        cout << "Please enter your name:" << endl;
        getline(cin, b);
        for (int i =0; i<b.size(); i++) {
            if  ((b[i] >= 'A' && b[i] <= 'Z') ||
                   (b[i] >= 'a' && b[i] <= 'z')) {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
                cout << "Please enter your name:" << endl;
                getline(cin, b);

            }
```

any suggestions thanks guys !

Comment: You wrote it that way.

Comment: It checks specifically if the value is a letter, and if it is a letter, it prints an error message. Rubber duck programming might help.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard library have [many nice algorithmic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), for example one called [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) which will return `true` if any element in the range passed to causes a predicate to return `true`.

Can be used with [`::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) like this

```
if (std::any_of(std::begin(b), std::end(b), ::isalpha))
{
    // There is at least one alphabetic character in the string
}
```

<sub>***Important note:*** The `std::any_of` function was introduced in C++11. Some compilers need special flags to enable C++11. Very old compilers and standard libraries might not have the function at all.</sub>

Comment: using this, i get an error " name.cpp:9:85: error: no matching function for call to ‘any_of(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)
name.cpp:11:70: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Predicate’’"

Comment: @Tommylee2k You have included the necessary header files (`<algorithm>` for `std::any_of`, and `<cctype>` for `std::isalpha`)? Oh and `std::any_of` was introduced in C++11, you might need to add a flag to enable C++11 depending on your compiler.

Comment: I build with "g++ -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c "%f"
here's the code of the whole function, perhaps i'm overseeing something:
`    void setName(std::string& b) {
        bool isValidName=false;
        while (! isValidName) {
            std::cout << "Please enter your name:" << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, b);
            if (std::any_of(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::isalpha )) 
                isValidName=true;
            else 
                std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        }
    }`

Comment: @Tommylee2k I think I know what it is, instead of `std::isalpha` try `::isalpha`. There are namely *two* `std::isalpha` in the C++ standard library, one from [`<cctype>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and one from [`<locale>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha). By using `::isalpha` you explicitly uses the one from `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 0):

please try to avoid repeating yourself (like you did with "getline")

 If you have to, rethink your algorithm ... in your case it could be something like " repeat the entry while there's no correct name entered", which can be coded exactly that way: 
this way, if you want to change the code in place A, you cannot forget to also change it in place B (and all the other places you eventually copied it to) ;-)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

void setName(std::string& b) {
    bool isValidName=false;    // nothing entered yet
    while ( !isValidName ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter your name:" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, b);
        if (std::any_of(std::begin(b), std::end(b), ::isalpha)) {
            isValidName=true;    // correct name entered
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string name;
    setName(name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```